# JAVA Object/String method overload

Tags: java

Just out of curiosity I tried this example.

```
public class Class1 {

    public void method(Object obj){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public void method(String str){
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void main(String... arg){
        new Class1().method(null);
    }

}
```

The output being "String". I want to know on what basis the JVM decides to invoke method taking String as argument and not Object.

Comment: Isn't this a compile error? Something about ambiguous parameters?

Comment: Apparently not. I wish it was.

Comment: Nothing ambiguous about this, @Thilo. It would be ambiguous if the first method accepted `Integer` and the second `String`, since then neither of them would be "more specific" than the other.

Comment: @Joni: Yes, not ambiguous if you know all the exact rules of the spec in detail. But a bit unclear if you don't. It cannot be denied that method selection rules have become quite complex with the introductiong of varargs, generics and autoboxing (of course this particular case has been there since Java 1). I find it weird that Java (which otherwise often leans towards verbose and explicit) is so "flexible" here. Makes for good quiz questions, but not really helpful in everyday's programmer life.

Comment: If you overload with Integer parameter, this will result in compile error.
Between String and Object, Object is superior and String is more specific so JVM will choose String however between String and Integer, there is no comparison and hence JVM will get confuse and throw ambiguous error at compile time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever more than one overloaded methods can be applied to the argument list, the most specific method is used.

In this case either of the methods can be called when passing `null`, since the "null type" is assignable to both `Object` and to `String`. The method that takes `String` is more specific so it will be picked.

Comment: how can i call the least specific method ??

Comment: Use type casts. For example, `method((Object) null)`

Comment: i use that for now. but lets say i am using this method as a exposed method of a library. so i dont want user to do all this type casting and all. user will just pass the value and i have to programmatically redirect the control to appropriate method. is there any other way ? 
@joni

Comment: You can use the reflection api to list the methods of a class or object, and then call the one you think is most appropriate. Sounds like this should be an independent question on Stackoverflow

Comment: @Joni method((Object) null) still called the string parameterized method

Comment: Nice answer, I was searching for C# and just to leave here at it's the same there.

Comment: @Coder17, no. it does not. can you share your code snippet?

Answer (score 12):

Whenever there's Method Overloading, the JVM will search for the method from the most specific type to least specific type

Comment: I suggest editing your quote from `most closest` to `most specific type` would be more appropriate in terms of programming lang.

Comment: Made correction. Thanks for that. I meant the same, however your words make more sense.

Comment: It's the compiler that decides which method should be called, not the JVM.

Answer (score 7):

See the [JLS specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method

It is one of the puzzle of [Java Puzzlers by Joshua Bloch](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1373963411&sr=8-1&keywords=Java+Puzzlers) - **Puzzle 46:** *Case of the Confusing Constructor*

Answer (score 2):

> *Java Compiler chooses the most specific method.*

**String** is a more specific type compared to the **Object**.

Answer (score 0):

Becaue you are passing **null** in calling method and you defined void method(String str)
And String always initlize with null. it will find that matching parametrized method.
Thats y u got "str" on console.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing method overloading, jvm tries to the next in hierarchy. For e.g. if you overload methods with long and int, but invoke method by passing byte, it will first go to int as it is next in hierarchy to byte.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of method Overloading

The most specific method is chosen at compile time.

As 'java.lang.String' is a more specific type than 'java.lang.Object'. In your case it returns String.